# "org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path" Error (May need to include table twice)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate to implement a Search page where different criteria may or may not be used. One criterion is an `ID` in `SpecialTable`. Another criterion is an `"Or"` in either `MainTable` or `SpecialTable`. Everything is optional.

Suppose I provide both Criterion #1 and #2. In this case, I want to join to `SpecialTable` **twice separately**, with different aliases, because these criteria don't depend on each other.

```
// Optional Criterion #1
if (searchCriteria.getSpecialId() != null) {
    criteriaQuery.createAlias("specialTable", "specialTableJoin1", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
    criteriaQuery.add(Restrictions.eq("specialTableJoin1.id", searchCriteria.getSpecialId()));
}   

// ...

// Optional Criterion #2
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(searchCriteria.getRequestPublicationTitle())) {

    criteriaQuery.createAlias("specialTable", "specialTableJoin2", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

    String titleForQuery = "%" + searchCriteria.getRequestPublicationTitle().replaceAll("^.*,", "").trim() + "%";
    Disjunction requestOrPublicationTitle = Restrictions.disjunction();
    requestOrPublicationTitle.add(Restrictions.ilike("title", titleForQuery));
    requestOrPublicationTitle.add(Restrictions.ilike("specialTableJoin2.publicationTitle", titleForQuery));
```

ERROR:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: specialTable
```

Any solutions? My aliases are different, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old Hibernate bug - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879 - still open since 2005!

The only solution is to define all aliases **beforehand** rather than for each used criterion. But this could be a problem if different JoinTypes are used in alias creation (INNER vs. LEFT_OUTER_JOIN). If it's all the same JoinType, you're set.

The workaround I went with is to define a common LEFT_OUTER_JOIN where both INNER/LEFT_OUTER_JOIN were required. The Left Join still works with Criterion #1 because it's constrained by Value=..., so there's no real difference from the original Inner Join.

```
// Prepare aliases (joins)
// -----------------------
if (searchCriteria.getSpecialId() != null || !StringUtils.isBlank(searchCriteria.getTitle())) {
    // Note: LEFT JOIN for both Special ID and Title,
    // since Hibernate Criteria API only allows 1 alias & join per Table (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879), and the 2nd criterion requires a Left Outer Join
    criteriaQuery.createAlias("specialTable", "st", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);                                                  
}
// ... All other aliases prepared ...

// Actual Criteria
// ... use the "st" single alias
```